# Install iOS device drivers on Windows without installing iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows, driver

I have a Windows PC that doesn't have iTunes installed, because I don't want it. But I still want to be able to use other software to transfer data from my iPad, which means I need the drivers for it.

Apparently, they only install with iTunes, but is it possible to install them standalone, with no other software needed?

Comment: couldn't you install then uninstall iTunes?

Comment: @abc905 I haven't tried that, but I presume that would uninstall the drivers with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this tip from [DiskAid website](http://support.digidna.net/entries/22586737-Run-DiskAid-without-iTunes-installed):

You need to manually install the required driver, the "Apple Mobile Device Support" or AMDS.

1. Download the iTunes installation package from [the official Apple Website](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/).
2. You need a program that can open a CAB file and extract contents from it. [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [WinRar](http://www.rarlab.com/) can do it.
3. Inspect the content of the iTunes installer `iTunes64Setup.exe` (that you downloaded in step 1) with 7-zip (right click, 7-zip, Open archive). 7-zip will show the files inside that installer file.
4. Extract `AppleApplicationSupport.msi` and `AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi` from the installer file to harddisk.
5. Run `AppleApplicationSupport.msi` and then `AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi`.

After AppleMobileDeviceSupport64 is installed, windows should be able to detect the iDevice.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but it is still a common "issue" of Apple

You can install the free drivers provided by Copytrans company

Go "Downloads" page and download "CopyTrans Drivers Installer"

**https://www.copytrans.net/download/**