# Is it possible to use MTP with iPhone without installing iTunes?

Tags: iphone, windows, driver

I want to transfer photos to the windows computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually install the required driver, the **Apple Mobile Device Support** (or AMDS).

> 1. Download the iTunes installation package from the official Apple Website.
> 2. You need a program that can open a CAB file and extract contents from it. 7-zip or WinRar can do it.
> 3. Inspect the content of the iTunes installer iTunes64Setup.exe (that you downloaded in step 1) with 7-zip (right click, 7-zip, Open
>      archive). 7-zip will show the files inside that installer file.
> 4. Extract AppleApplicationSupport.msi and AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi from the installer file to harddisk.
> 5. Run AppleApplicationSupport.msi and then AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi.

After AppleMobileDeviceSupport64 is installed, windows should be able to detect the iDevice.

[Source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34651/install-idevice-drivers-but-not-itunes?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

iTunes is not responsible for photo import [on either Mac or PC].

Windows can use MS Photo Gallery [or equivalent depending on your Win version] as an importer & organiser, the closest free equivalent to Apple's Photos app.

The upside is you don't have to dig around in the file system at all - which is not recommended - the app can handle it all for you.

Re pjctech's answer - idk whether that is also a required first step before my solution will work.